# replicating google protocol buffers output file without proto file

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

I have a project file that was created by some software at a large company. After talking with the company I was able to get a snippet of code that is used to  read and write the project files. I was told that is uses protocol buffers but I was unable to get the proto file that was used to generate the C++ code. After asking for it and getting more questions than answers, would it be a realistic assumption that they basically recreated google protocol buffer on their own without a proto file?
Is there a way to construct a proto file based on the c++ code?

Is there a way to verify that i'm even working with Google Protocol buffers data?

Comment: Did they say they used google protobuf? Or just that they used protocol files, because that could mean anything.

Comment: @FantasticMrFox Yes they are using google protocol buffers. But they didn't use a proto file to do so . they created all the definitions on their own. I'd like to create a proto file that would generate equivalent code in c++ but also give me the ability to code in other languages.